# Lock draft option after to publish my custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

In my plugin, I have a custom post type with a specific behaviour.

The administrator after to publish it, he should not be able to set the post as draft again.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `transition_post_status` hook, which allows you to hook into when a post is transitioning (or anytime a post is saved). In the example below, we check if the post is apart of your custom post type. Then we see if the old status was published and if the new status is not published, we throw an error.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'tps_no_draft_after_publish', 10, 3 );
function tps_no_draft_after_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( ( 'publish' !== $new_status && 'publish' === $old_status ) && 'my-custom-post-type' === $post->post_type
    ) {
        wp_die('Posts that have been published cannot be set as draft.');
    }
}
```

Additional reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Comment: This solution let the user change the post status and click on the save button, I would like to show the correct view without the possibility to modify the status.

Comment: Based on the information here (https://github.com/r-a-y/unlisted-posts/issues/6 and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13794) it looks like the Gutenberg editor does not (yet) allow for modifying these options.

Comment: Following up on this, it looks like the post status are set via this file https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/editor/src/components/post-visibility/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to display the submit box wihtout draft button.

The code to display this box is generated by the function `post_submit_meta_box` from `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`.

As we can see, there is no hook to overwrite some code, so this following solution step by step is the best way I found without using a dirty solution like hide with css or js :

## 1 - remove the metabox "submitdiv"

```
public function remove_customized_metabox(){    
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', $post_type_slug, 'side' ); 
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', "remove_customized_metabox", 10 );
```

## 2 - add my "submitdiv" customized metabox

> You must use a different id than `submitdiv` to show your metabox
>   In my case I prefixed with underscore : `_submitdiv`

```
add_meta_box( 
    "_submitdiv", 
    __( "Publish" ), 
    "my_custom_callback", 
    $post_type_slug, 
    'side', 
    'core', 
    [ 'show_draft_button' => false ] 
);
```

## 3 - write the view in the callback function

Based on `post_submit_meta_box`, write your callback function like this :

```
public function my_custom_callback(?\WP_Post $post, array $callback_args){
    global $action;

    $post_type = $post->post_type;
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type);
    $can_publish = current_user_can($post_type_object->cap->publish_posts);
    ?>
    <div class="submitbox" id="submitpost">
    ...
    if( $callback_args['show_draft_button'] ) {
       //display the draft button
    }

    ...
}
```

## 4 - change `_submitdiv` by `submitdiv` with jquery

> if you want to change the publish date, `post.js` use the anchor `#submitdiv` so you  must change the id.

```
wp_enqueue_style( "metaboxsubmitstyle", "path/css/admin-metabox-submit.css" );
wp_enqueue_script( "metaboxsubmitscript", "path/js/admin-metabox-submit.js" );
```

### admin-metabox-submit.css

```
#poststuff #_submitdiv .inside {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

### admin-metabox-submit.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#_submitdiv").attr( 'id', "submitdiv");
    });
});
```